# Creating a Carriage Return Button in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, carriage-return

I'm trying to create a button that when clicked, creates a carriage return. For example, at the top of my webpage there are buttons that output words when clicked. Upon the click of the next button, the new word is placed immediately after the other words. I need this button to create a new line for the output words above it. I've tried a few codes along the lines of this:

```
<input type="button" value="Return"
onclick="document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML=
document.getElementById('outputDiv').innerHTML + \br;">
<div id="outputDiv"></div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid using `.innerHTML`, instead consider the *DOM methods* of `node.appendChild` and `document.createElement`

```js
function newline() {
    document.getElementById('outputDiv').appendChild(
        document.createElement('br')
    );
}
// after input exists, select it with your favourite method to attach listener
document.querySelector('input[value="Return"]').addEventListener(
    'click',
    newline
);
```

When attached this way the *HTML* doesn't need an *onclick* attribute anymore either

```html
<input type="button" value="Return" />
<div id="outputDiv"></div>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/L6fvhcuu/)

Comment: I'm still having some issues implementing this. I've been editing this coding now, and just need to figure out how to achieve the output.     <script>
var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");        
var t = document.createTextNode("Return");       
btn.appendChild(t);                                
document.body.appendChild(btn);  
</script>